# Idempotency for increment via PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to achieve itempotency when incrementing a database column via PUT? (For example a credits-count in a purchase process)

Comment: Sounds like increment is a non-idempotent operation...

Comment: @Joe: Not really, you can have an idempotent increment (repeatly doing it only has the same effect as doing it once). I did laugh initially, though, as that was my first reaction as well.

Comment: Is the increment of your column constant? If it is I would go for POST and not for PUT, since you won't need to show some details for the user (ids, values,..). You could just increment on your application and also dont need it to be idempotent.

Answer (score 7):

Send a unique transaction id with every request, store all executed transaction ids and don't react to requests with a transaction id that you already saw.

Comment: Jinx! I deleted mine, didn't add any value over yours.

Comment: Ah, I think that's exaclty what we need. Are there any best practises / plugins for that?

Comment: This way works, but if the increment is constant you lose that property. It will just work as you can increment by any amount or you have to do a validation and see if the id is correct